# Use Offset with Excel SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, header, vba

I'm working on an excel file to collect information from others closed Excel files
The provider is *Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0* and everything works fine (almost).

In order to have updateable query, I used the command `HDR = no` in order to have column name like F1, F2, F3... and I retrieve the name after (see the code below, code from Stack Overflow).

However, with the command `Union All`, I also retrieved the headers as data, if I collect data from 5 files, I'll get 5 headers.
So I'm looking for a solution to retrieve header with command `HDR = NO` on Excel SQL query (start at line 2 in each file).

I tried `OFFSET` command in SQL query but I get an error message.
I also tried to get the row number in the original file but I didn't find the command.

Do you have any idea to help me on this issue?

Many thanks in advance, 
BR

Code for information:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SqlUnionTest()    
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim objConnection As Object
    Dim objRecordSet As Object

    strConnection = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "User ID=Admin;" & _
        "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
        "Mode=Read;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;"";"

    strQuery = _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source1.xlsx' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=NO;'] " & _
        "UNION " & _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source2.xlsx' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=NO;'] " & _
        "UNION " & _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source3.xlsx' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=NO;'] " & _
        "ORDER BY ContactName;"

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.Open strConnection
    Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(strQuery)
    RecordSetToWorksheet Sheets(1), objRecordSet
    objConnection.Close   
End Sub


Sub RecordSetToWorksheet(objSheet As Worksheet, objRecordSet As Object)
    Dim i As Long

    With objSheet
        .Cells.Delete
        For i = 1 To objRecordSet.Fields.Count
            .Cells(1, i).Value = objRecordSet.Fields(i - 1).Name
        Next
        .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset objRecordSet
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the starting and ending row while querying the excel file. So Instead of -

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]
```

Use This -

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A2:end]
```

A2 - it will start reading from 2nd row.
end - will read until the sheet has data. So suppose, if you want to only some rows from SHEET1. Use this -

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A2:A10]
```